# dirmult package in R

Tags: r, distributions, maximum-likelihood

I am trying to use the dirmult package in R to find the parameters of the dirichlet multinomial distribution. However When I run the code, I see that it appears to be minimizing the Likelihood rather than maximizing. Here is a sample trace:

```
> foo <- dirmult(data)
Iteration 1: Log-likelihood value: -108256.762432151
Iteration 2: Log-likelihood value: -112024.171181739
Iteration 3: Log-likelihood value: -114816.893733128
Iteration 4: Log-likelihood value: -117178.454519049
Iteration 5: Log-likelihood value: -119081.542746927
Iteration 6: Log-likelihood value: -120547.115475672
Iteration 7: Log-likelihood value: -121631.658731926
Iteration 8: Log-likelihood value: -122408.210532819
Iteration 9: Log-likelihood value: -122950.170423675
Iteration 10: Log-likelihood value: -123321.325905601
Iteration 11: Log-likelihood value: -123572.241418431
Iteration 12: Log-likelihood value: -123740.558811607
Iteration 13: Log-likelihood value: -123853.029548595
Iteration 14: Log-likelihood value: -123928.062303726
Iteration 15: Log-likelihood value: -123978.091582544
Iteration 16: Log-likelihood value: -124011.444469511
Iteration 17: Log-likelihood value: -124033.679213468
Iteration 18: Log-likelihood value: -124048.502105592
Iteration 19: Log-likelihood value: -124058.383928014
Iteration 20: Log-likelihood value: -124064.971772997
```

Typically, this does not happen. On the dirmult example data set:

```
> fit <- dirmult(us[[1]],epsilon=10^(-12))
Iteration 1: Log-likelihood value: -3291.68283455695
Iteration 2: Log-likelihood value: -3282.90699227135
Iteration 3: Log-likelihood value: -3277.28960275919
Iteration 4: Log-likelihood value: -3274.32118891593
Iteration 5: Log-likelihood value: -3273.14865155825
Iteration 6: Log-likelihood value: -3272.87180418868
Iteration 7: Log-likelihood value: -3272.84788154144
Iteration 8: Log-likelihood value: -3272.84761179787
Iteration 9: Log-likelihood value: -3272.84761175372
Iteration 10: Log-likelihood value: -3272.84761175372
Iteration 11: Log-likelihood value: -3272.84761175372
```

Why is this happening? Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it was a problem with initscalar being very far off from the correct value. Setting it to 1 seems to work much better than the default value of 30.

```
fit <- dirmult(data,initscalar=1)
Iteration 1: Log-likelihood value: -49211.1885266878
Iteration 2: Log-likelihood value: -48023.7318371376
Iteration 3: Log-likelihood value: -47055.7760604743
Iteration 4: Log-likelihood value: -46314.3393587051
Iteration 5: Log-likelihood value: -45788.3361403143
```

Comment: I was able to get results similar to  your initial pathological results by putting in certain 'init' values with the example dataset. That was when I started asking about initial values.

Answer (score 0):

(I struck this paragraph now that the questioner has convinced me its inapplicable regarding `dirmult`.)  <strike>Most likely it is minimizing the likelihood in the residual sums (on the log scale), but therefore maximizing the likelihood in the model. The fact that log-likelihoods behave like chi-squared statistics means that you can "decompose" them into packets that sum to the total. This doesn't express the aspects of the mathematical features in precise language but is my attempt to express it in colloquial terminology. (This should apply to any method that reports log-likelihood and not just to dirmult.)</strike>

Looks like dirmult is sensitive to starting conditions. Have any negative values?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by: 'Most likely it is minimizing the likelihood in the residual sums.' Are you referring to Least squares estimation? Why would this be reported as likelihood?

Comment: The fitting process tries to maximize the log-likelihood accounted for by the model and the residual log-likelihood becomes the difference between the NULL model's LL (the one with no covariates)  and that of the fitted model.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about w.r.t. covariates. I am just fitting the model with dirmult and without using any explanatory variables. I'm not familiar with the methodology they are using, but it appears to be something other than direct numerical optimization of the MLE. And whatever they are doing is actually decreasing the likelihood every iteration, which is not the case with the example data that they give.

Comment: No negative values, although the values tend to be fairly low. I'm doing brand affinity analysis, and so the columns are brands, rows are customers and the cells are the counts of items that each customer has purchased in that brand. The matrix is sparse, and the counts are low.

Comment: When you say it is sparse, do you mean that is the class of the R object or do you mean you have lots of zeros or NAs?

Comment: It has many zeroes